# Proof of conjecture by Burklund-Clausen

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Today, a [short talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7Va32nfnEU) by Dustin Clausen was uploaded onto the IHES youtube channel in which he states he and Robert Burklund have recently proved a longstanding conjecture. I assume this is known to some people, so my question is what was the conjecture they proved?

Comment: The timestamp is about 5:30, for what it’s worth. You should have asked on MO, which the specialists are more likely to visit.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the comments are closed on youtube or else I would've asked there. If it gains no traction I will post on MO.